# Thumbnail grid with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to make responsible grid with thumbnails using bootstrap and knockout. Currently i have the next html:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- ko if: toys().length == 0 -->
    <div>No toys in category</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko foreach: toys-->
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 previewGridItem">
        <a class="thumbnail" data-bind="attr: { href: '#!/toy/' + id }">
            <img data-bind="attr: {src: images[0] ? images[0] : '/Content/img/NoImage.jpg' }" />
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Sometimes i'm getting correct grid. But in most cases (ofcourse depending on size of images and length of item's names) i've got something like this: 
[image: previewGrid].

How to properly align items? The most simple answer is to set height of images to constant, but then the proportions of images are ruined. More over, i want images resizing including height. Text are limited by 2 lines per image.

Live demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y02nwfb5/)

Comment: Have you tried resizing the images' height and width? You could pretty easily calculate the desired width based on the original height/width ratio.

Comment: @JohnBarton I'm already resizing images that max side of image is 100px. But proportions are different.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at **Gridalicious** plugin - it's created exactly for this type of situations. It's also pretty fast, and can be easly adjusted for your needs with built in configurable parameters as well as simply editing uncompressed version of plugin accordingly to your needs.

http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/

Comment: I need images aligned both in horizontal rows and vertical columns. It seems that Gridalicious align only columns.

Comment: Oh, then maybe this is what are you looking for?
http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Answer (score 0):

For now, i solved problem using jQuery plugin mentioned in [comment by Artanis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31927125/1758830). I've also have to use plugin [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) because i have ajax call which loading images. In result i've written next code:

```
window.imagesLoaded(".previewGridItem", function(instance) {
    $(".previewGridItem").matchHeight();
});
```

I do not think that it's the best solution, because now i have 40kb (12Kb minimized) libraries only to align images. But for now i can't find a solution only with css.